# R emacs-ESS not plotting on mac

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I have a new mac and have downloaded ESS-emacs and have been running R. But it does not produce any plots with plot() pie() or hist().

I have tried show(), X11() and pdf() but none of them work. The R process actually ends when I try this for example:

> plot(1:10)

Process R finished at Sat Feb 23 21:39:08 2013

Answer (score 3):

new macs don't come with X11. You need to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac).

Answer (score 1):

When I run ESS/R on a mac, plot(1:10) should bring up a plot in a Quartz window.  You shouldn't need to resort to x11().  I like the Quartz driver as it allows you to navigate through the history of plots, see the Quartz menu of the R application.

To see if your R has support for Quartz, type capabilities() and see what it says for 'aqua'.

Comment: Running `capabilities` from within Emacs/ESS also crashes. Running it from within the Mac version of R displays a prompt to navigate to the XQuartz website.

Comment: When you say it "crashes" do you mean Emacs is killed?  Or, just that the *ESS* buffer becomes unresponsive?  (IN which case does C-g help?)